# Extract year and month from timestamp(6)

Tags: oracle, timestamp, extract, iso8601

I have database, where i have inserted timestamps(6) in this format : 
`18-AUG-14 02.49.27.000000000 PM` .

I want to extract it into this: 2014-08

Its called ISO 8601

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll need to use the [to_char](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) function to extract the year-month from timestamp.

```
select to_char(timestamp, 'yyyy-mm') from your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in this way -

```
select extract(year from timestmp) || '-' || extract(month from timestmp) from texmp1;
```

Hope this helps.

Here is the table structure:

```
    create table texmp1 
(
timestmp timestamp
);
```

Comment: That would make 2014-8, not 2014-08.

Comment: im sorry, maybe i confused you with the word "extract"....@KimBergHansen is right, its not ISO format